# How to get Google Secure Token Authorization from a website

Tags: firebase

I have a website where I want to login using a cli, however I need to provide the AuthorizationToken for the request to securetoken.googleapis.com. I have failed to find what request the website makes to get that token.

I do have an api key and an obbcode and I think those are they key to recieveing the authtoken, but how and where do I need to make that request?

googeling, workaround is selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hit me if i got you wrong. as far as i can see you want to login using a cli.

and inorder to do that you need to obtain an Authorization Token for Firebase Authentication for this you need to make a request to the securetoken.googleapis.com endpoint. This endpoint is responsible for generating the token based on the provided API key and OBB code.

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key={YOUR_API_KEY}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code={YOUR_OBB_CODE}'
```

here replace {YOUR_API_KEY} with your actual API key and {YOUR_OBB_CODE} with your OBB code.

after doing this you will receive a response containing the Authorization token then use this token to authenticate and access the protected resources on your website.

it will be better if write code to handle any errors or exceptions also.

Comment: I think this is the correct idea, however for my case I seem to get an error
An error occurred during the request: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=api_key


I have the following sign in link from which I'd need to get the refreshtoken in order to generate the authtoken 
https://example-website-prod.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey=AIzaSyCsyxwwMvs6AlhW1U3kfnsjjsa3w0&mode=signIn&oobCode=m_tPnwXhsdj3yg7H2HhWWrRpb-hgHSJFNA85eA&continueUrl=https://example.com/account/signup&lang=en

Comment: can you try the following ? 

 1.Go to the Firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/) and navigate to your project.

 2.Click on the gear icon (Project settings) in the top-left corner of the console.

3.In the General tab, scroll down to the "Your apps" section and select the web app for which you need to generate or update the API key.

4. Under the Firebase SDK snippet, copy the value of the apiKey field.

5.  Open your code editor and locate the Firebase configuration section.

6. Replace the existing API key with the copied value from the Firebase console.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Rainy sidewalks but the API Key is the correct one, the same as in the signup link

Comment: can you try it with another api key ?just for the cross check .

Comment: The solution is to run the request to the initApp